# What exactly is super in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, super, objective-c-runtime

As far as I know, it's a pointer to the superclass. It's hard-wired with the superclass, and not dynamically figured out at runtime. Would like to know it more in detail...

Anyone?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

[**`super`**](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectivec/Articles/ocDefiningClasses.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH12-BAJHDGAC)

Essentially, it allows you to use the implementations of the current class' superclass.

For the [gritty](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/objcruntimeref/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/tag/objc_super) [details](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/objcruntimeref/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/objc_msgSendSuper) of the Objective-C runtime:

`[super message]` has the following meaning:

> When it encounters a method call, the
>   compiler generates a call to one of
>   the functions objc_msgSend,
>   objc_msgSend_stret, objc_msgSendSuper,
>   or objc_msgSendSuper_stret. Messages
>   sent to an object’s superclass (using
>   the super keyword) are sent using
>   objc_msgSendSuper; other messages are
>   sent using objc_msgSend. Methods that
>   have data structures as return values
>   are sent using objc_msgSendSuper_stret
>   and objc_msgSend_stret.

So yes, it is static, and **not** determined at runtime.

Comment: Possibly cause for a new question, but `super` behaves oddly (or "normally", if you think that way) in categories.  That is, it treats the category as a subclass (not an override), so `super` is then the original, unmodified class.  Sort of.  Sometimes.  "It's complicated."

Comment: "gritty" "details" - links are dead

Answer (score 29):

It's a keyword that's equivalent to `self`, but starts its message dispatch searching with the superclass's method table.

Answer (score 20):

`super` is *not* a pointer to a class.  Super is `self`, but when used in a message expression, it means "look for an implementation starting with the superclass's method table."

Comment: This is not true for class methods.

Answer (score 6):

These blog postings on [what is a meta class?](http://cocoawithlove.com/2010/01/what-is-meta-class-in-objective-c.html), [getting subclasses](http://cocoawithlove.com/2010/01/getting-subclasses-of-objective-c-class.html) and [classes and metaclasses](http://www.sealiesoftware.com/blog/archive/2009/04/14/objc_explain_Classes_and_metaclasses.html) may give you some insight on the internals of this.