# What is "super" in Objective-C?  ( self != super )?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, macos

I've read the question below, and the story *SEEMS* simple:

[What exactly is super in Objective-C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3095360/what-exactly-is-super-in-objective-c)

Yet ...

```
- (id) init
{
    NSLog(@"self=%p, super=%p", self, super);
}
```

That prints out "self=0xa83dc50, super=0xbfffe8d0".  The addresses are NOT THE SAME???!?!?

That second address seems like a "special value" or something. What does it mean?

***Thanks to bbum for pointing out that this value is the stack address of a special struct used by the compiler to implement the "super" behavior.***

---

<strike>I can call [super init] and the call seems to work, or at least, nothing explodes ... not immediately.  Calling [((id)0xbfffe8d0) init] fails hard with EXC_BAD_ACCESS.</strike>

Then there is the REALLY WEIRD part.....
I've got a piece of code that for no explainable reason throws a "NSGenericException: collection was mutated while being enumerated" exception.  Inside a DIFFERENT object (basically a wrapper that has a pointer to the NSEnumerator), commenting out the call to  "[super init]" causes the exception to not happen.  If I could, I'd put out a $$$ reward for an answer to THAT mind-bender.

"id sups = (id)0xbfffe8d0" ... that also leads to "collection is modified." ... WTF?  Ok, so I'm posting a 2nd question for that bizzariotity ...

I originally came here with one of those "bizarre symtoms" bugs, that turned out to be entirely unrelated (typical for such things): [Does casting an address to (id) have side-effects??? Is Address 0xbfffe8d0 special? (fixed: issue was with _NSCallStackArray)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9961623/does-casting-an-address-to-id-have-side-effects-is-address-0xbfffe8d0-speci)

However, the content above the line is still valid, and the response still excellent.  Read it if you want to understand ObjC just a little bit deeper.

Comment: Aside from your other issues, 0xbfffe8d0 is presumably a code address, but there's no reason to expect it would be the same from one compile to the next.  Casting that literal value to a pointer is basically just creating a pointer from a random number.

Comment: Actually, it's a stack address, which isn't the same thing as a code address.  It's not even the same from one run to the next!

Comment: A stack address isn't even the same from one instant to the next in the same run.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You are messing with the man behind the curtain and he is punishing you for it... :)

`super` is a bit of compiler magic, really.  When you say `[super doSomething]`, the compiler will emit a call to `objc_msgSendSuper()` instead of `objc_msgSend()`.  Most of the time -- there are some special cases.

In general, you should treat `super` as **only a target for method calls**.  It should never be stored anywhere and should never be considered anything *but* that target expression for messaging.

In fact, uses of `super` that involve storage should likely be flagged by the compiler.

In terms of your bug, that sounds an awful lot like there is either corruption of memory, an over-release, and/or concurrency going on.  You'll need to provide more code related to the enumeration and other relevant code to deduce further.

Comment: heh, "messing with the man behind the curtain" :)  I posted a 2nd question with more details about that bug.

Comment: If you're interested, `super` is implemented (or used to be) as a pointer to a structure. The structure contained two elements, the first of which was `self`, and the second was the superclass, which tells the runtime which class to start looking in.

Comment: AH!  That explains the strange value.  It's the stack address of that funky struct you mention.

Comment: Yup;  if you were to look at the assembly, the compiler lays down said struct and then `objc_msgSendSuper()` uses the `isa` of the `superclass` to start the method search while using the struct's reference to `self` as the target of the method call.  An implementation detail (thanks to @ughoavgfhw for going there!!).