# What's the difference between [super init] and [[ParentClass alloc] init]?

Tags: objective-c, ios, oop, inheritance

Consider following interfaces:

```
@interface Bar : NSObject

@end

@interface Foo : Bar

@end
```

What's the difference between...

```
@implementation Foo

- (id)init
{
    return [super init];
}

@end
```

... and...

```
@implementation Foo

- (id)init
{
    return [[Bar alloc] init];
}

@end
```

...?

**EDIT:** for clarification I am adding more code...

```
/* =============
 * GenericCell.h
 * =============
 */

// imports, etc.

typedef enum {
   GenericCellStyleFoo,
   GenericCellStyleBar
} GenericCellStyle;

@interface GenericCell : UITableViewCell

- (id)initWithStyle:(GenericCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier;

@end

/* =============
 * GenericCell.m
 * =============
 */

// imports, etc.

@interface FooCell : GenericCell

- (id)initWithReuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier;

@end

@interface BarCell : GenericCell

- (id)initWithReuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier;

@end

@implementation FooCell

- (id)initWithReuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    // *************************************************************************
    // This will actually call GenericCell's 'initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier:',
    // hence the "loop"!
    // *************************************************************************
    self = [super initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        // various subviews or whatever to make this cell so special...
    }
    return self;
}

@end

@implementation BarCell

- (id)initWithReuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    // *************************************************************************
    // This will actually call GenericCell's 'initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier:',
    // hence the "loop"!
    // *************************************************************************
    self = [super initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        // various subviews or whatever to make this cell so special...
    }
    return self;
}

@end

@implementation GenericCell

// some useful code...

- (id)initWithStyle:(GenericCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    if (style == GenericCellStyleFoo) {
        return [[FooCell alloc] initWithReuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    }
    else if (style == GenericCellStyleBar) {
        return [[BarCell alloc] initWithReuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    }

    return nil; // doesn't really matter for sake of this example
}

// some useful code...

@end

/* =================================
 * SomeTableViewControllerInstance.m
 * =================================
 */

// imports, etc.

@implementation SomeTableViewControllerInstance

// some useful code...

- (UITableViewCell *)cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    GenericCellStyle style = [self styleDoesntMatterHowForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell;

    // dequeue and all that...

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[GenericCell alloc] initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    // set labels, or whatever...

    return cell;
}

// some useful code...

@end

// End of file
```

Comment: Where did you see the second way used? It doesn't seem like it would be useful.

Comment: I am in a situation where if someone calls init of a class Foo, internally I might actually create an object of type "FooSomething : Foo" or "FooSomeOtherThing : Foo" in different cases. Since both Foo* and Foo have "init" if you do [super init] inside either Foo* you will get your self into a loop.

Comment: For one thing, you're leaking in the second.

Comment: Mainly, the first will return a Foo object while the second will return a Bar object (and leak the created Foo).

Comment: Exalted -- The logic you describe will result in an infinite recursion regardless.  There must be some logic in your `init` that will decide to NOT create the inner object at some point in the recursion.

Comment: Voring to close because you are asking for a code review, not for an explanation between super init and parent alloc init.

Comment: @Jano That's not true, although I am sorry. I couldn't make my self clear without it...

Comment: Instead of calling `alloc/initWithStyle`, call GenericCell `+newGenericCellFactory`, and put the logic you want in there.

Answer (score 1):

When you use `super`, you aren't referring to a parent class. You are really referring to the object you are creating, in a way. See this question:

[What exactly is super in Objective-C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3095360/what-exactly-is-super-in-objective-c)

There's a lot of links and information in the answers that really explain it in detail.

Comment: Is there anything wrong if had to still call "self = [[ParentClass alloc] init]" if I had to break the loop? I know "[super init]" is the way to go, but I can't seem to break it otherwise.

Comment: I guess you could. I don't know why you would though. This article is kind of interesting, but note the update at the bottom: http://www.wilshipley.com/blog/2005/07/self-stupid-init.html

Comment: I don't think I understand your issue with using `[super init]`. Why would it return a different object type depending on the situation? Can you post some code from your classes?

Comment: @exalted -- What is this "loop" you want to "break"?

Comment: @HotLicks I hope my new edit will clear things a little bit.