# Purpose of super keyword in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c

i asked meaning of "SUPER" keyword in view didload method
eg. [**super** viewdidload] kindly tell me correct meaning of this keyword.

Comment: super = calling the superclass of the current class.

Comment: Check `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3095360/what-exactly-is-super-in-objective-c`

Answer (score 0):

The keyword `super` refers to the superclass of the caller.  In usage, it's a way to invoke the superclass's implementation of the current method.