# custom tableview cell explaination

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have created custom tableViewCell,and I don't understand why do i need to init it 2 times , override init and super.init ,what this code does, please explain

```
class tablecell: UITableViewCell {
    override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: .subtitle, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    }
}
```

Comment: If you are not doing anything in the init, you can ignore the method. From the code you are actually doing nothing in that method anyways.

Answer (score 1):

This: `super.init(style: .subtitle, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)` doesn't mean you are `init`ing two times.

`super` allows us to use the defaults of the table view cell with our custom code to work with.

So `super` says that: *I'll use my own code with defaults*.

More info: [What exactly is super in Objective-C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3095360/what-exactly-is-super-in-objective-c)